# Как отправить данные через последовательный порт, который определён в другом файле

Tags: c++, qt

Есть файл mainwindow.cpp, в котором есть экземпляр класса QSerialPort. С помощью
`port->write(data)` я отправляю через последовательный порт массивы данных. И мне нужно, чтобы по сигналу clicked() кнопки с помощью слота setSettings() через этот порт отправлялся массив, который определён файле can_settings.cpp.

can_settings.cpp:

```
connect(ui->setSettings, SIGNAl(clicked()), this, SLOT(saveSettings());

void CAN_Settings::saveSettings()
{
static CAN_cfg;

CAN_cfg[0] = 0x83;
CAN_cfg[1] = 0 | ui->RTR_EN->isChecked() << 6;
}
```

CAN_cfg нужно передать через port, который находится в mainwindow.cpp

Comment: 1. скорее всего, для начала нужно подключить нужный хедер, что бы объявления стали видны в нужном месте. 2. массив скорее всего должен быть доступен в каком то виде в том месте, где будет отправка.

Comment: Отправка массивов происходит из mainwindow.cpp. Но теперь мне понадобилось через тот же порт отправить массив но из can_settings.cpp. Отправка происходит с помощью клика по кнопке в can_settings.ui Но делать can_settings.ui public'ом, чтобы появилась возможность по сигналу этой кнопки отправлять данные в mainwindow.cpp неправильно, насколько я знаю

Comment: то есть, если сделать public, то проблема решается быстро?

Comment: Если сделать этот массив глобальным и ui public'ом, то да, как мне кажется, если бы я знал точно, вопрос бы не задал)

Comment: Тогда сделайте функцию-геттер, которая будет возвращать этот массив (или его копию). И готово.

Comment: Но это не решает моей проблемы. Я не понимаю, как передать этот массив в port при нажатии кнопки

Comment: куда Вы хотите его передать? в порт? или передать в другой "файл"?

Comment: В порт с помощью port->write()

Comment: тогда Вам либо массив нужно сделать доступным (но любые способы это сделать Вы откидываете) или сделать доступным переменную, которая хранит объект port там, где доступен массив.

Comment: В том и вопрос, как объект port сделать доступным в файле с массивом и ui

Comment: изначально вопрос не так звучал, но ок. Никто не мешает создать свой сигнал, у которого будет параметр, который будет содержать указатель на порт. И все. и теперь в слоте будет доступно.

Comment: Можете привести пример кода?

Comment: а кнопка, по нажатию которой все происходит, находится тоже в коде окна, где хранятся данные?

Comment: Кнопка сделана через ui. Данные из этого ui заносятся в массив и при нажатии кнопки должны передаваться в порт. Так что, да.